# How to find the script that is activated when clicking on a button?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, button, google-chrome-devtools

Suppose I have a button in a webpage and I want to find the function that is revoked when the button is clicked. How do I find this script in Chrome developers tools?

Comment: You should have done a search before posting this one.

Answer (score 3):

In the Chrome debugger tools, please go to the **Source** tab. On the extreme right, you'd see the list that says *Watch, Call Stack, Scope* etc. If you expand **Event Listener Breakpoints**, you'd see the list of event listeners you can put a break-point on.

Expand the **Mouse** event listener, select **click** and proceed to click the button. It  should hit the break-point.

[image]

Hope it helps!

#### Edit by Gideon: Blackboxing

You may find yourself stepping into library event handlers when you use the Event Listener Breakpoints. You can avoid stepping into these every time by right-clicking and selecting 'Blackbox script' as per below:

[image]

Comment: I tried it. But it sends me to built-in files of angular.js, such as angular.js, socket.io.js, jquery.flot.js. 

The function I'm looking for is probably inside a controller.

Comment: @CrazySynthax I have added to Dumbledore's nice answer on Event Listener Breakpoints to deal with your issue with stepping into library code. This should help.

Comment: @Gideon, I tried to do what you've offered and although chrome notifies that the file has been blackboxed, the debugger still reaches these files.

Comment: @CrazySynthax You need to play though the remaining breakpoints first after doing the blackboxing. If you long click on the Resume button, it will give you option to do a Long Resume, which skips breakpoints for 500 ms. Once it's finished, re-click on the button and it will not step into the blackboxed script(s).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ctrl + shift + j` to open the chrome dev tools and go to the sources tab. There you can see all scripts that are being used by the page. You can place breakpoints to determine when events are happening, and can use `ctrl + f` to find anything specific (i.e. button id, class).

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't help me :-(. 
I see dozens of javascript files. I want chrome to lead me to the specific function.

Comment: To find a file you can use ctrl-p and start typing. Unless you are searching for a function that you yourself did not write and are trying to locate where it might be?

Comment: I search for a function I didn't write myself and I don't know where it is.

Comment: Then I would see @Gideon edit above, that should be exactly what you're looking for.